# How to automate RDO or VMware workstation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, virtual-machine

My requirement is to automate remote desktop, VMWare, and NoMachine. I am not getting which module I can use in python, How to automate these? I got to know about pywinauto but with that, I guess I can just launch any app but not automate it, then how to do that? Thanks in advance.
If it is confusing, Please tell me how can I automate the GUI of a remote PC using  RDO?

Comment: `automate remote desktop, VMWare, and NoMachine` is not clear. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Actually, I have to automate all, VMware workstation, NoMachine, and RDO.  I would have one script for each and automate my needs, e.g. **I would launch RDO then in RDO I will open a file write something and save or open a web browser and automate that too.**

Comment: Remote Desktop doesn't provide any GUI context of the remote program. You have to keep the automation script on the remote machine only.

Comment: What about VMware?

Comment: VMware interface itself can be automated. But the app in the guest OS must be automated inside the virtual machine (i.e. remotely as well). If you have pre-built guest OS image with correct network settings, copying and running automation script on this VM is definitely possible. If OS installation automation is needed, there should be another way like PXE boot. Some install scripts could be integrated into the installation image then.

Comment: Of course, guest OS could be Windows only for now.